# return value to main

Tags: c++, function, return-value

In the code below I am trying to have the variable fullName be populated with whatever I enter during the operation of the function namecheck. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help and thank you for it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string namecheck();

int main()
{ 
    cout<<fixed;

    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string fullName;
    char action;
    int pin;
    int pinTry =1;
    int actionsTaken =0;
    int joeyPin = 4433;
    int mildredPin = 2849;
    double joeyTotal = 3742.55;
    double mildredTotal = 19.36;
    double withdraw;
    double deposit;

    namecheck();
    cout<<fullName;
}

string namecheck(){
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string fullName;
    string completeName;
    double joeyTotal = 3742.55;
    double mildredTotal = 19.36;

    cout<<"Welcome to Blah National Bank!\n";
    cout<<"What is your first name?\n";
    cin>>firstName;
    if (firstName == "END"){
        cout<<"User totals: \n"
            <<"Joey Stowy:\t"<<setprecision(2)<<joeyTotal<<endl<<endl
            <<"Mildred Moredebt:\t"<<setprecision(2)<<mildredTotal<<endl<<endl;
    }
    if (firstName != "END"){
        cout<<"What is your last name?\n";
        cin>>lastName;
    }
    fullName = firstName+" "+lastName;


    return fullName;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `firstName` and `lastName` don't really need to be declared in `main`.

Comment: To debug, you can try "cout<< namecheck();"  instead of "cout <<fullname;".

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
namecheck();
cout<<fullName;
```

to:

```
fullname = namecheck();
cout<<fullName()
```

.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `namecheck()` in `main`, assign the result to `fullName`:

```
fullName = namecheck();
```